# Doctrine 2 - ManyToOne Nullable relation not work

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a strange error, on my Symfony4 project.
One of my relation is a ManyToOne with nullable true, like this:

```
class UserComic
{
 ...
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Series")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_series", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $series;
...
}
```

then I try to create a new UserComic with the $series attribute set to NULL, but i receive this error:

> "Entity of type App\Entity\UserComic is missing an assigned ID for
> field  'series'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity
> requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist()
> is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you
> need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly."

As the field is not setted to nullable. Any advice?

Comment: A PK can not be or contain null. As such `nullable` with `@ORM\Id` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

ID means UNIQ and NOT NULLABLE.

You are on a ManyToOne relatsionship (on the many side) that break the UNIQ property of ID

You set the joinColumn as nullable, that breaks the NOT NULLABLE PROPERTY

Comment: Yoshi already answered, all because of my carelessness. Thanks for the sql tutorial :D

Comment: Yoshi already answered, all because of my carelessness. Thanks for the sql tutorial :D